# How do you read 遅ランチ?

Tags: readings

I read `遅ランチ` and while I think the meaning is pretty clear ("late lunch" unless I'm mistaken), I wasn't sure how to read it. I wanted to say `おそ`, but the lack of okurigana suggests to me that isn't the case. This leads me to guess that it's `チ` which is the on'yomi. Is it `遅{ち}ランチ`, or is the okurigana implied perhaps, i.e. `遅{おそい}ランチ`, or am I over thinking this and it's just `遅{おそ}ランチ`.

Or D: None of the above.

Comment: Another possibility could be `おくれランチ`, although I happen to agree with @user1205935's answer below.

Comment: 「はやめし」「はやべん」って言うし、「おそめし」「おそべん」「おそランチ」になるのかな？（「はやばん」「おそばん」は関係ないか～）

Comment: @Chocolate 「はやい」っても「い」がなくなるんですか～知らなかった　＝＾。＾＝

Comment: 漢字で書くと・・・　[早番]{はやばん} ・ [遅番]{おそばん} ← 勤務時間のこと、[早飯]{はやめし} ・ [早弁]{はやべん} ← 早めにとる食事(弁当)のこと。「[早便]{はやべん}」「早いウ×コ」ではありませ（（殴

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think 遅いランチ is quite common, and so is 遅め(の)ランチ. In either case 遅 is read おそ, so I would think 遅ランチ is just a shortening to be read as おそランチ.